# Boost date_time: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost9gregorian10greg_month15as_short_stringEv

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to run a plugin I wrote for the flight Simulator X-Plane 11.
It's written in C++ and, when compiled, placed in X-Planes "plugin" folder.

It's already working fine on Windows and macOS, but I can't get it to run on Ubuntu.

The issue seems to related to the boost 1.72.0 library I'm using: date_time.

On Windows, I'm linking it against: libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_72.lib

On macOS, it's also working fine linking against: libboost_date_time.a

However, on Linux, I'm always getting some kind of "undefined symbol" error.
I managed to let it compile and dynamically link libboost_date_time.so.1.72.0 later on, but I'm always getting this error message:

```
undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost9gregorian10greg_month15as_short_stringEv
```

I also tried using different boost versions (1.71 from apt-get and 1.77 which I've compiled myself), without success.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: One possible cause for your problems could be a confusion between the different boost versions, i.e., if the header file used in compliation and the linked .so file aren't from the same version

Comment: Another option is that the linking of the .so file simply doesn't work